# Set objects to empty NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, swift, xcode6

I can create an NSDictionary

```
    var namesDictionary=Dictionary<String,String>()
    namesDictionary["Jacob"] = "Marry"
```

But, when I create a empty dictionary like coded below, line 1 i okie, but line 2 (adding values) throws an error.

```
    var namesDictionary =[:]
    namesDictionary["Jacob"] = "Marry"
```

Error is "Cannot assign to the result of this expression". Is there any other way to assign the values.

Answer (score 14):

It looks like it's an issue with swift interpreting the type of your dictionary. Try explicitly typing your empty dictionary.

```
var namesDictionary: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]
namesDictionary["Jacob"] = "Marry"
```

I think a better use for `[:]` is for emptying an already defined dictionary. If you add a third line `namesDictionary = [:]`, you will be able to call `namesDictionary["Jacob"] = "Marry"` again since the compiler knows what type of dictionary it is from the inital declaration.

Comment: Then it should have thrown error in the first line itself.

Comment: The first line is fine. It creates an empty dictionary, but the key/ value types aren't Strings. The dictionary at this point is pretty much useless since it won't accept any key value pairs

Comment: Okie, what is the difference between the var namesDictionary=Dictionary<String,String>()  and var namesDictionary: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]

Comment: Pretty much just syntactic sugar. Both create an empty Dictionary<String, String>

Comment: namesDictionary.setValue("Marry", forKey: "Jacob") works

Comment: setValueForKey: is part of NSKeyValueCoding, not specific to dictionaries. If you call `namesDictionary["jacob"]` after it, you'll see it hasn't changed the dictionary